# Dual boot on two ssd's

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

Dual booting and ubuntu are quite new to me as I only installed ubuntu a month ago on my laptop (I'm not using it every day since I got windows as well).

I just bought all the parts to build a new desktop computer (I'm waiting for them to arrive) and I'm planning to install both windows and ubuntu on it. The thing is I am going to have two SSD's (one I bought and one I get for free with the motherboard I bought). The one I bought is way faster, so I would like to install windows on it with all the other programs and games I plan to install.

I am willing to install ubuntu on the second ssd, but still keep some space on it (I want to allocate 100 Gb to Ubuntu and "give" the rest for windows). How could I do that?

I'm sorry if I appear like a noob but I kinda am in this matter :3

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just be sure to install both systems in UEFI boot mode, or if really desired you can use BIOS boot mode. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. May be easier just to only connect one drive at a time. If both drives connected Install Windows first, and only use Something Else install option with Ubuntu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 1):

This is a combined Windows-Ubuntu Question and Windows is off-topic here, so I would install the other OS first on its own hard drive in MBR mode and let the BIOS figure out how to do it:  when you want to switch from that other OS to installing Ubuntu:

- reboot,
- hit the <kbd>F12</kbd> or whatever key the BIOS wants you to hit to boot from another drive drive, *and let the BIOS then fail onto USB/DVD* (whatever you're installing Ubuntu from).
- install Ubuntu taking only as much as you need (take the "Something else" option while installing Ubuntu)
- then boot back to that other OS and then allocate the free space on the second hard drive to it.

Especially: Install both OSes as bare as possible as you've never done this before as you're bound to [make a mistake somewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) and you want to avoid losing anything valuable.

Comment: And start out with installing windows first, much less error prone as the other way around.

Comment: @Videonauth that's what I said:  "Install *the other OS* first"  **:-)**